# Generate NuGet with targetFramework=".NETCore5.0", using it in .net5 C# project not possible

Tags: c++, .net, .net-core, nuget

I am getting following error:
NU1202: Package xxx is not compatible with net5.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0). Package xxx supports: netcore50 (.NETCore,Version=v5.0)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `.NETCore` and `.NETCoreApp` are not the same thing. [NuGet's docs on target frameworks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/target-frameworks) says that `.NETCore` is "Windows Store". I'm not sure if that's the same thing as UWP, although in the doc it does say that `uap` can use `netcore`.

Anyway, .NET 5's canonical target framework identifier is `.NETCoreApp` (same as all the earlier .NET Cores, 1.0 to 3.1), which is different.

It's all just an unfortunate choice in names that leads to unnecessary confusion, but it's the history of how we got here.

In short, your .NET 5 project can't use packages designed for UWP.